# Изменить порядок наложения объектов во FrameLayout

Tags: android, framelayout

Во `FrameLayout` вложены три `RelativeLayout`(`relativeLayout1`,`relativeLayout2`,`relativeLayout3`), один из которых (`relativeLayout3`) в разметке xml лежит последним, и, следовательно, он выводится на экран поверх остальных.

В процессе работы приложения (не в методе `oncreate`), в какой-то момент требуется изменить этот порядок, и `relativeLayout3` поместить под `relativeLayout2`. Возможно ли это сделать?

PS

Естественно, что вариант "в какой-то момент" создать новый `RelativeLayout` (копию `relativeLayout2)`, добавить его во FrameLayout программно, и таким образом он отрисуется поверх остальных, мне известен.

Comment: может стоит пересмотреть разметку? три RelativeLayout это не лучшее решение, может скинете макет и Вам помогут его упростить?

Comment: Может проще работать с видимостью в вашем случае?

Comment: @Дамир Арманов да, с видимостью было бы просто - сделала невидимой и все, но это совсем меняет внешний вид. Все layout имеют картинки (не на весь слой). При клике по картинке она увеличивается в размерах и должна быть над всеми остальными (т.е. все остальные должны остаться "фоном").

Comment: @Евгений Суетин, да, если невозможно поменять порядок слоев во FrameLayout, придется менять разметку) Это понятно.

Comment: Попробуйте поработать с параметром 'elevation'.

Answer (score 1):

Нашла ответ на свой вопрос в техдокументации, как ни странно)

Оставлю решение здесь, т.к. искала его полдня в интернете, и видела, что люди интересуются тем, как изменить порядок наложения view друг на друга.

[Вот здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#bringChildToFront(android.view.View)) описан метод `void bringChildToFront (View child)`, который меняет z-index потомка таким образом, что последний оказывается выше остальных.

Только есть два нюанса, может, потому что у меня приложение для мин.API 16:

1 нюанс, как указывать (View child), 
если указать так:

```
relativeLayout2= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout2);
frame.bringChildToFront(relativeLayout2);
```

то, не работает.

А вот если указать так:

```
frame.bringChildToFront(findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout2));
```

то работает.

И еще в техдокументации написано, что для версий ниже KITKAT нужно вызывать `requestLayout()` и `invalidate()` у родителя, Z индекс потомков которых нужно изменить, чтобы заставить его перерисоваться с новым порядком (z-индексом) потомков.
Но у меня все итак работает.
Возможно, что-то не так поняла, ибо не специалист.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью метода `view.bringToFront()` можно в `Layout` перемещать `view` поверх остальных.

java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
// метод указан в атрибуте view android:onClick в xml файле activity_main
    public void start(View view) {  
        view.bringToFront();   
    }
}
```